# How to loop through a macro variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I have an example like this:

```
proc sql;
select dealno into :deal_no 
from deal_table;
```

Now I want to traverse the variable `deal_no` now containing all dealno in table deal_table but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do with this.  While there are certainly some valid reasons for traversing a macro variable list, nearly all of the time there is a much better solution using existing data step programming methods.

Comment: I want to take a list of item and then inspect each item if they satisfy a specified condition.For example:
%macro loop;
---use loop here to retrieve items in list ---
insert into table my_table
select * from your_table
where deal_id not in (item)
%mend;

Comment: If that's what you want to do, then do it in SQL, or in a data step, without the macro variable loop.  Looping in macro language is nearly always wrong - it is the slow, slow way to do it.  If you're just doing the above once, then Keith's solution is better - gets you all of the values in one macro variable.  If you are doing some sort of complicated join-insert, it can undoubtedly be done either in SQL or a data step without macros.

Comment: Thank for advice. I'm just starting with SAS so I don't know much about it. You quoted "do it in SQL, or in a data step, without the macro variable loop", so may i see your solutions also ? I want to know solutions from SAS experienced users

Comment: I'm using the approach descibed in my answer when I have a few distinct values to iterate over (10 or so), and a large amout of work to do for each of those values. I usualy have a macro that does an analisys for a given month, and If I have to do that analisys for a list of months that I have to calculate from some dataset, I use that approach.

Comment: You'd have to more specifically describe what you're doing to get more specific advice - I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do from your description in the comment above.  But in general, macro variables aren't intended to hold data except in small amounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do

```
%put &deal_no;
```

you can see that it only contains the first value of `dealno`, not all of them.
To avoid that you can do something like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table counter as select dealno from deal_table;
    select dealno into :deal_no_1 - :deal_no_&sqlobs
    from deal_table;
quit;

%let N = &sqlobs;

%macro loop;
%do i = 1 %to &N;
    %put &&deal_no_&i;
%end;
%mend;

%loop; run;
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is add 'separated by' to the sql code, which will add a delimiter to the values.  You can then use the SCAN function in a data step or %SCAN in a macro to loop through the values and perform whatever task you want. Example below.

```
proc sql noprint;
select age into :age separated by ','
from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put &age.;

data test;
do i=1 by 1 while(scan("&age.",i) ne '');
    age=scan("&age.",i);
    output;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select age into :ageVals separated by ' '
  from ageData;
quit;  

%put &ageVals;

%macro loopAgeVals;   %let i = 1;   %let ageVal = %scan(&ageVals, &i);

  %do %while("&ageVal" ~= "");
    %put &ageVal;

    %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
    %let ageVal = %scan(&ageVals, &i);   
  %end; 

%mend;

%loopAgeVals;
```